# Get total social share count (Facebook, Twitter, Google+. Pinterest)

Tags: social-sharing

I'm pulling the individual share counts for the social media I've mentioned using the following code snippet in my theme's function.php:

```
$facebook_like_share_count = function ( $url ) {

    $api = file_get_contents( 'http://graph.facebook.com/?id=' . $url );

    $count = json_decode( $api );

    return $count->shares;
};

$twitter_tweet_count = function ( $url ) {

    $api = file_get_contents( 'https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' . $url );

    $count = json_decode( $api );

    return $count->count;
};

$pinterest_pins = function ( $url ) {

    $api = file_get_contents( 'http://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?callback%20&url=' . $url );

    $body = preg_replace( '/^receiveCount\((.*)\)$/', '\\1', $api );

    $count = json_decode( $body );

    return $count->count;

};

$google_plusones = function ( $url ) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://clients6.google.com/rpc" );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '[{"method":"pos.plusones.get","id":"p","params":{"nolog":true,"id":"' . $url . '","source":"widget","userId":"@viewer","groupId":"@self"},"jsonrpc":"2.0","key":"p","apiVersion":"v1"}]' );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Content-type: application/json' ) );
    $curl_results = curl_exec( $curl );
    curl_close( $curl );
    $json = json_decode( $curl_results, true );

    return intval( $json[0]['result']['metadata']['globalCounts']['count'] );
};
```

I'm calling them into my single.php with the following code:

```
<?php $url = get_permalink( $post_id ); echo $facebook_like_share_count ("$url");?>
<?php $url = get_permalink( $post_id ); echo $twitter_tweet_count ("$url");?>
<?php $url = get_permalink( $post_id ); echo $pinterest_pins ("$url");?>
<?php $url = get_permalink( $post_id ); echo $google_plusones ("$url");?>
```

This works fine.

Now, I'm trying to find a code snippet that will add the share count of those 4 services and shows the total share count - probably something similar to [this here](http://www.codedevelopr.com/articles/get-social-network-share-counts-for-a-url-with-my-php-class/).

**EDIT:** I have an important question.

**Is it possible that the code above is slowing down my blog?**

I've already contacted my hosting service and they told me it must be something like a plugin or php files. I haven't really updated any plugins recently and P3 Profilier just tells me who the usual culprits are. But I noticed right after calling that function in my single.php my server sometimes loads super slow - even gets timeouts on speed checking sites.
Any ideas?

**EDIT2:** After a lot of testing it really seems to be this code (when echoed) that slows down the page. *shrugs*
Guess I have to stop using it?

I haven't been able to get it to work yet.
I hope you can help me out here.
Thank you so much!

Comment: `$total_count = $facebook_like_share_count + $twitter_tweet_count + $pinterest_pins + $google_plusones;`

Comment: @ialocin Can I just copy and paste that into my function.php as is and echo it into my single.php? Thank you. :)

Comment: The reason why it is slowing down your page is because you are requesting data from 4 different sites. So all of those needs to be loaded before your script continues to process. This is bad. Add a cron that does this for you, or cache the page. Don't load this on every page load.

Comment: @ChristineCooper What is a cron? Sorry, like I said I'm not very good with codes. I thought the page is cached as I'm using the W3 Total Cache plugin.

Comment: Look into "WP Cron", it runs on set intervals. You create a function that checks the share counts, stores them via update_post_meta() and you use this value to display the share count locally rather than requesting external files on every page load. Although I am not sure if this is the approach you should take. Personally, I would do all of this via jQuery, this way, you let all the action to happen on the client side, which it should be with this type of thing.

Comment: @ChristineCooper I've seen approaches with jQuery. Unfortunately I didn't get any of them to work yet which is why I was asking for advice here. :)

Comment: I suggest that you ask for a jQuery solution over at stackoverflow instead because this is not a WordPress specific answer and I doubt you will receive a response here. I would still give another chance on google with this because it is a very commonly requested feature so there should be a lot of code available. =)

Comment: @ChristineCooper I googled like crazy and tried all the code snippts I could find. Nothing worked. Thanks, I will. :)

Comment: I sometimes work with transients for social share counts, meaning the count values are getting updated in a certain time interval and not on every page load. And, no, you can't just copy&paste it and use it in your single.php, because the variable wouldn't be in scope.

Comment: @ialocin **Transients**! Yes! I will need to update my own code now. OP, see: https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API

Comment: @ialocin I just hit up an answer to this using transients. Nice one.

Answer (score 3):

Okay. @ialocin made a note about [Transients](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API). By some odd reason, I have not come across this yet. Previously, I used to display counts by:

- jQuery (client side loading)
- Page caching (when storing counts locally)
- Cron updating count values
- And most recently, stored all counts in post meta and updated the meta every 100 loading of the page... pretty wild.

But no, there is something better. I lot better. Transients. Transients. Transients... chant it for hours... Once you've meditate and returned, delve into the following code which I customized for you:

```
// Check for transient. If none, then execute code
if ( false === ( $data = get_transient( 'trans_' . $post_id ) ) ) {

    /* action */
    $facebook_like_share_count = function ( $url ) {

        $api = file_get_contents( 'http://graph.facebook.com/?id=' . $url );

        $count = json_decode( $api );

        return $count->shares;
    };

    $twitter_tweet_count = function ( $url ) {

        $api = file_get_contents( 'https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' . $url );

        $count = json_decode( $api );

        return $count->count;
    };

    $pinterest_pins = function ( $url ) {

        $api = file_get_contents( 'http://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?callback%20&url=' . $url );

        $body = preg_replace( '/^receiveCount\((.*)\)$/', '\\1', $api );

        $count = json_decode( $body );

        return $count->count;

    };

    $google_plusones = function ( $url ) {
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://clients6.google.com/rpc" );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '[{"method":"pos.plusones.get","id":"p","params":{"nolog":true,"id":"' . $url . '","source":"widget","userId":"@viewer","groupId":"@self"},"jsonrpc":"2.0","key":"p","apiVersion":"v1"}]' );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Content-type: application/json' ) );
        $curl_results = curl_exec( $curl );
        curl_close( $curl );
        $json = json_decode( $curl_results, true );

        return intval( $json[0]['result']['metadata']['globalCounts']['count'] );
    };

    // store data in array
    $data = array (
        $facebook_like_share_count,
        $twitter_tweet_count,
        $pinterest_pins,
        $google_plusones
    );

    // Put the results in a transient. Expire after 6 hours
    set_transient( 'trans_' . $post_id, $data, 6 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS  );
}

if (is_array($data)) {

    $facebook_like_share_count = $data[0];
    $twitter_tweet_count = $data[1];
    $pinterest_pins = $data[2];
    $google_plusones = $data[3];

}
```

Firstly, make sure that `$post_id` is already set previously to adding this code as it uses the ID to add a unique handle to the transient.

We are storing cached data in the database temporarily by giving it a custom name and a timeframe after which it will expire and be deleted.

So, for every 6 hours, it updates the cached array. It's as simple as that. See the comments for clarification.

## EDIT:

As per discussions in the comment thread, I have adjusted the code. Firstly, make sure you have the share functions inside your `functions.php` file (I believe you already have this in your current setup), then in your `single.php` file, add the following where you want to `get` the count values.

```
// get post id
$post_id = get_the_ID();

// get perm url to be used for share count functions
$url = get_permalink( $post_id );

// Check for transient. If none, then execute code
if ( false === ( $data = get_transient( 'trans_' . $post_id ) ) ) {

    /* action */
    $facebook_like_share_count ("$url");
    $twitter_tweet_count ("$url");
    $pinterest_pins ("$url");
    $google_plusones ("$url");

    // store data in array
    $data = array (
        $facebook_like_share_count,
        $twitter_tweet_count,
        $pinterest_pins,
        $google_plusones
    );

    // Put the results in a transient. Expire after 6 hours
    set_transient( 'trans_' . $post_id, $data, 6 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS  );
}

if (is_array($data)) {

    // these are your variables containing the share count
    $facebook_like_share_count = $data[0];
    $twitter_tweet_count = $data[1];
    $pinterest_pins = $data[2];
    $google_plusones = $data[3];

}
```

Please read the comments I put inside the code for clarification.

Comment: You just made me smile happily with how happy transients make you :)

Comment: Hello. Thank you so much for your hard work.
I tried to put your code into my theme's function.php, but if I do so my page won't load. I suppose there's a syntax error? :(

Comment: What? No, this code should go whereever it was originally taken from. I am guessing single.php

Comment: @ChristineCooper I had the code I originally posted in my question in my function.php and then echoed it into single.php. I though I was supposed to do the same with your code snippet?! ^^;

Comment: Please update your question with the *full* code you use in your functions.php file and the *full* code you use to call your functions in your single.php or loop-single.php file. This way, I can actually see what's going on and adjust the code for you.

Comment: @ChristineCooper Thank you. I edited my question. Let me know if you also need to see my complete function.php and I'll upload it to pastebin.

Comment: `file_get_contents()` will not work with URLs on all servers. Use the HTTP API instead.

Comment: @toscho How would that code look?

Comment: @japanworm Something like this: `$count = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_safe_remote_get( 'http://graph.facebook.com/?id=' . $url ) ) );`

Comment: See my updated code...

Comment: @ChristineCooper I tried again. I don't think you've changed the code snippet I'm supposed to put into my function.php. There must be a syntax error somewhere. As I'm horrible with code, I cannot figure it out myself. Maybe a code snippet in the function.php cannot start with "if"?? I don't know.. :(

Comment: I did not change the code in your functions.php file, that should be the exact same code that you used previously that **was** working according to you? So you shouldn't get an error in your functions.php file if you are using the exact same working code.

Comment: @ChristineCooper If I use the code posted in my question, I don't get this error. If I use the code you posted in your answer, I do.

Comment: Do you place my code in your single.php file? Also, please paste the error in its full as a comment here and outline the part of the code the error message references.

Comment: @ChristineCooper There is not an error message. My blog stops loading as soon as I put the code into the function.php which usually indicates a syntax error.

Comment: @ChristineCooper So, I suppose I should just give up if the code is not working in my function.php for whatever reason? Thank you. :)